# Libgdx GestureListener to Handle Hold TouchDown

Tags: java, android, eclipse, libgdx

I'm using libgdx to develop mygame.

I'm using GestureListener to handle my touch events. 
My goal is to make the character moves right or left when the player holds touch on the screen.

The problem is, GestureListener doesn't have any method to handle this. If I'm using pan, the player has to swipe to trigger the method. Also, GestureListener does not have touchUp method so I cannot combine touchDown and touchUp.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Libgdx [`GestureDetector`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/input/GestureDetector.html) is designed to detect high-level "gestures" like swipe and pinch and pan, it cannot report other sorts of touch events.

There are a couple options for getting the information you want:

First, you can use a more direct [`InputProcessor`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/InputProcessor.html) to get the raw touch events and track long touches.  You may need to use an `InputMultiplexer` to share the inputs between your existing gesture listener and the new input processor.

Second, you can [poll for the is-being-touched state](https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/InputPolling) in your update method.  Just check `Gdx.input.isTouched(x)`, and then `Gdx.input.getX(x)` and `Gdx.input.getY(x)` (for `x` in the range of 0 to 20, depending on how many active pointers you want to support).

Comment: Hey, thx, I have used input processor and it worked.
But I still don't understand about InputMultiplexer, am I have to use that? I have read from this https://code.google.com/p/libgdx-users/wiki/handlingUserInput but I still don't understand.

Comment: `InputMultiplexer` is necessary if you want to use multiple input processors at once.  Its not required otherwise.  Probably best to ask a new question if you have more specific concerns.